# Change the background image dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image

I would like to modify the image in the background with the help of a comment.

The images come from the tmdb API.
So I think you have to create a background image component and pass it on to the URL.

I know that CSS has the background-image property, but it works for static images ...

What is the best method, I would like to make this component reusable.

Comment: why not just `<img src="yourimg" />` ?

Comment: do `<element style={{backgroundImage: this.state.url}}><element>` where `element` may be a div or a span or whatever

Comment: What are the steps you've already done and wasn't able to achieve that ?

Comment: I tried with a tag img in a div in a component, but I did not see how to make a background image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you would have to do it.

1. Create your `<div>` and its `style` with a default `background-image`
2. Create 3 `<button>` to triggers your function `changeImage()` and provide a parameter
3. Change the `style.backgroundImage` with `JavaScript` such as below:

```js
function changeImage(category){
  document.getElementById('div-bg').style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://source.unsplash.com/320x240/?' + category + '")';
}
```

```css
#div-bg {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/320x240/?sky");
}
```

```html
<div id="div-bg"></div>

<button onclick="changeImage('nature')">Nature</button>
<button onclick="changeImage('animal')">Animal</button>
<button onclick="changeImage('fire')">Fire</button>
```

If you have any question, please ask!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this.

I had not planned to use buttons, I just pass a props "image-url" that will contain the path.

Comment: It is only to explain what you're asking for. Use only `document.getElementById('div-bg').style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://source.unsplash.com/320x240/?' + category + '")';` if you prefer. That example is showing how to do it,

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your help, I put the solution under this house.

Comment: Anytime, that was a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

By doing this it works, I have my background. But I did not manage to do it with a reusable component

```
import React from 'react';

  const VideoDetail = ({ title, description, background }) => {

  const IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";

  const backgroundStyle = {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundAttachment: 'scroll',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    backgroundImage: `url(${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${background})`
 };

 return(
    <div>
      <div style={background !== undefined ? backgroundStyle : null }>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
} 
export default VideoDetail;import React from 'react';
```